# Angular 2 HTTP post method doesn't send data to request.JSON in Grails Action

Tags: json, angular, typescript, grails

Not able to get data in **request.JSON** which is passed from Angular 2 HTTP POST method.

Grails action is getting invoked. But **request.JSON** is always getting empty value {} though I am passing data.

**ANGULAR2: HTTP POST Method:**

```
return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/test/saveStatus', { status: 'Test' })
  .map((response: Response) => response.json());
```

**Grails Action:**

```
class TestController {

    def saveStatus() { 

        def request = request.JSON
        /*
         other codes...
        */
    }

}
```

Comment: Actually I don't know `request.JSON` means. Am waiting for some other answers.

Comment: where you have send `body/data` part in the POST Request ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to post the data to controller

```
 postmethod() {
            let dataUrl = `http://localhost:8080/test/saveStatus`;
            let status="Test";
            let body = JSON.stringify(status);
            return this.http.post(dataUrl, body)
                .map(response => response.json())
                .catch(this.handleError);
        }


 def saveStatus([FromBody]string status) { 

        def request = request.JSON
        /*
         other codes...
        */
    }
```